# Is there anyway to send keystrokes to the terminal in node?

Tags: node.js

In particular I would like to send

```
ctrl + l
```

to clear the terminal so each time I test my script the terminal is clean.

Comment: XY problem: if you want to clear the terminal, try asking about clearing the terminal, not about sending keystrokes :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: yes, but if there are two ways to do it and one is console.clear and the other is by sending keystrokes i will learn more from the second way which is why i phrased it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on linux :

```js
console.log('\033[2J');
```

If you're on Windows, I think this works : (sets the cursor at 0,0)

```js
var util = require('util');
util.print("\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H");
```

We are basically using the power of ANSI escape codes:

> These are ANSI escape codes. The first one (`\033[2J`) clears the entire screen (`J`) from top to bottom (`2`). The second code (`\033[1;1H`) positions the cursor at row `1`, column `1`.
>
> *https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062051/8932080*

You may want to read the full Wikipedia article [just here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to fully understand it.

Comment: !! worked!. thanks. will mark as answer in a few minutes when it lets me.

Comment: For those of you who, like me, have no clues on what the above code is about, just read this answer which explains it very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062051/8932080